# how to count number of un-ordered partitions of a number

Tags: java

I am really stuck at this problem.

In this problem, you are given a 2xN board. You need to fill in non-negative numbers in this board in such a way, that:

1. The sum of all the numbers filled = N
2. Each of the 2 rows
   consist of numbers in non-increasing order
3. Each of the N
   columns consist of numbers in non-increasing order.

In how many ways can this be done, given the number N?
Two ways are considered different if there is a cell in the board which has different numbers.

The output should be the number of ways the matrix can be formed.
The matrix can have repetitive numbers and zero can be used. The matrix should not have increasing numbers but equal numbers can be filled along side each other.

Example:

input-> 5

output->16

Comment: could you specify an example? is floating point number allowed?

Comment: example is already there and no floating point number.

Comment: I dont see example?  Do you mean where you said Example:?  Because i think he meant an example of actual solutions, not just the count.

Comment: the output has to be the number of ways in which the matrix 2XN can be formed. So the output is 16.

Comment: Right the definition requires assumptions, there is a 2xN board AND the sum must only add to N, so then the numbers _can_ include zero? And numbers can repeat? So numbers must always appear in decreasing order, but we can fill the right side with zeros?

Comment: yes, the number can be zero and the numbers can repeat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your example (input=5, output=16) I suppose only integer numbers are allowed.

One naive (brute force) solution is to use backtracing algorithm:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking

On this site you can see example with sudoku board being filled until solution is found.

==

For example:

You have array of integers with size 2N.

```
For position 0 you take first free number. 
If solution is not broken yet you go to position 1 of array.
If solution is broken - stop as cannot back anymore

  For position 1 you take next free number.
  If solution is not broken you you go to position 2 of array.
  If solution is broken you back to previous sten and take next free number.

    For position 2...
```

This is typically done with recursion. 
I think, on each position (recursion level) numbers can be taken from pool 0..N.

Try - good luck.

**EDIT:**

Here is valid solution (using backtracking algo):

```
private final int N = 5;

// 2 rows in one array [0..N-1, N..2N-1]
private int[] board = new int[2 * N];

// found solution counter
int found = 0;

/*
 * this method set next number to current position
 * and recursively go to next position.
 */
public void check(int position) {

    // if board is complete - check if valid
    if (position == 2 * N) {
        if (isValid()) {
            System.out.println("foun : " + Arrays.toString(board));
            found++;
        }
        return;
    }


    // if board is not complete - put all numbers (0..N) into current position
    // and recursively go to next position
    for (int v = 0; v <= N; v++) {
        board[position] = v;

        // if solution is already broken - step backwards
        // see: backtracking algorithms
        if (isBroken(position)) {
            return;
        }

        check(position + 1);
    }
}

public boolean isValid() {

    // condition 1
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        sum += board[i];
    }
    if (sum != N) {
        return false;
    }

    // conditin 2
    int prev = board[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        if (board[i] > prev) {
            return false;
        }
        prev = board[i];
    }
    prev = board[N];
    for (int i = N + 1; i < 2 * N; i++) {
        if (board[i] > prev) {
            return false;
        }
        prev = board[i];
    }

    // condition 3
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int top = board[i];
        int bottom = board[i + N];
        if (top < bottom) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // valid
    return true;
}

// simplified version of this method - but correct
public boolean isBroken(int current) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= current; i++) {
        sum += board[i];
    }
    return sum > N;
}

public void start() {
    check(0);
    System.out.println("found: " + found);
}
```

And program output for N = 5:

```
found : [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
found : [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
found : [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
found : [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
found : [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
found : [2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
found : [2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
found : [2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
found : [2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
found : [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
found : [3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
found : [3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
found : [3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
found : [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
found : [4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
found : [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
found: 16
```

Comment: @aradhna- I posted working code to above answer. Check if it is OK for your needs. This code can be speed up of corse (better isBroken method) but gives some point to start.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brute force way: since this is a 2xN matrix and the sum of all numbers must be N, the simplest solution is to fill the first row with 1's, and the 2nd row with 0's. Now you will need a recursive algorithm that takes a valid board, and removes 1 from any "free" position and add it to any legal position. That board is also a solution. By "free" I mean a number n at position [i, j] where [i+1, j] <= n - 1 and [i, j + 1] <= n - 1. You then recursively invoke the algorithm on the new boards, and save everything.

All that's left is to deduplicate solutions.

Example of the algorithm on input 5:
Initial solution:

```
11111
00000
```

The only "free" number is [0, 4]. Remove 1, the only legal positions are [0, 0] and [0, 1]. This gives you 2 new solutions

```
21110
00000
```

and

```
11110
10000
```

Now apply same algorithm again on both these solutions. Notice that the 2nd board now has 2 "free" numbers. Repeat until you get to

```
50000
00000
```

EDIT: Just had a lot of fun coding this example. Didn't test it, but that's where my head is going:

```
public void TwoRowBoard()
{
    var board = new int[2, N];
    //Create initial, simplest solution.
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        board[0, i] = 1;
    }

    var solutions = new List<int[,]>();
    RecursiveSolve(board, solutions);
}

private void RecursiveSolve(int[,] board, List<int[,]> solutions)
{
    var freeNumbers = GetFreeNumbers(board);
    foreach (var freeNumber in freeNumbers)
    {
        board[freeNumber.i, freeNumber.j] -= 1;
        var legalPositions = GetLegalPositions(board);

        foreach (var legalPosition in legalPositions)
        {
            var newBoard = Copy(board);
            newBoard[legalPosition.i, legalPosition.j] += 1;
            solutions.Add(newBoard);
            RecursiveSolve(newBoard, solutions);
        }
    }
}

private List<Coordinates> GetLegalPositions(int[,] board)
{
    //Position 0, 0 is always legal.
    var results = new List<Coordinates> {new Coordinates {i = 0, j = 0}};

    //Row 0
    for (int j = 1; j < N; j++)
    {
        if (board[0, j - 1] > board[0, j])
        {
            results.Add(new Coordinates{i = 0, j = j});
        }
    }

    //Row 1. Board[1, higher than N/2] are never legal positions.
    for (int j = 0; j <= N /2; j++)
    {
        if (board[1, j - 1] > board[1, j]
            && board[0, j] > board[1, j])
        {
            results.Add(new Coordinates{i = 1, j = j});
        }
    }

    return results;
}


private List<Coordinates> GetFreeNumbers(int[,] board)
{
    var results = new List<Coordinates>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 && j == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (i == 0)
            {
                if (j == N - 1 && board[0, j] > 0)
                {
                    results.Add(new Coordinates {i = 0, j = j});
                }
                else if (board[0, j] > board[1, j]
                         && board[0, j] > board[0, j + 1])
                {
                    results.Add(new Coordinates {i = 0, j = j});
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (j > N/2 && board[1, j] > 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Don't see how it's possible for board[1, N/2 or higher] to not be 0");
                }
                if (board[1, j] > board[1, j + 1])
                {
                    results.Add(new Coordinates{i = 1, j = j});
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return results;
}

public class Coordinates
{
    public int i { get; set; }
    public int j { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost positive this has a solution in closed form, or its similar to another problem with a solution in closed form.  I would do it programmatically with recursion.

So suppose you know a solution for N.  You want N+1.  So what you should do is take all the solutions for N and see where you can stick an extra 1 in there without breaking any constraints.  That is, super impose the N solution(s) on the N+1 board then try in all 2N places to add 1 without breaking constraints. Then store all of them in a set so they will be deduped.

In any case, its similar to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)